# Custom Agenda View based on headers?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use a pretty basic notes file that has headers like:

```
* Next Actions
** action 1
** action 2
* Deferred
** deferred 1
** deferred 2
etc.
```

I rarely use tags or todo states on the elements of my lists. So far I've only come across ways to create custom Agenda views by filtering the tags or todo states; I haven't found any info on filtering through headers instead.

Is this possible or is it not built-in into org-mode? I'm quite comfortable in lisp as I do all my coding (hobbyist) in Common Lisp but I'm not that familiar with eLisp.

Comment: The world of sorting and organization opens up when a user has keywords (aka todo state) and tags in the heading, so you it may behoove you to adopt a more org-mode approach to your setup.  Here is what I use, which matches what the Toodledo server uses and I synchronize with that:  `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "Active(a)" "Next Action(n)" "Canceled(c)" "Hold(h)" "Reference(r)" "Delegated(d)" "Waiting(w)" "Postponed(P)" "Someday(s)" "Planning(p)" "|" "None(N)")))`   **In what way(s) do you want to "filter[] through headers"?  An example of before / after would certainly help.**

Comment: @lawlist: So here's an excerpt of my file: 

* Captured
** '*' in evil highlights all words at point
** CAPTURED Email Kranti about WS 2015 <2015-03-20 Fri 08:21>
* Next Actions
** DONE Email Tarik about WS 2015 <2015-03-20 Fri 08:21>
* Deferred
** DEFERRED Times Car Plus registration
   SCHEDULED: <2015-03-23 Mon>

I would like to show items under the Deferred, Next Action, and Captured headings without having to resort to filtering for todo states, have them show up just by being under a particular heading. Right now I've implemented todo states since I can't figure out how to do it without.

Comment: It sounds like you want to restrict the view of your org file to a subtree. Does `org-narrow-to-subtree` on one of your top level headlines do what you want?

Comment: @erikstokes yep that does it but I can't seem to figure out how to use it in the agenda block view. Anyway thanks for the heads up.